# Import 3d buildings into Cesium

Tags: 3d, kml, geojson, cesiumjs

I have many buildings in CityGML format. Currently cesium does not parse citygml. I tried Geojson and KML formats as in Cesium official tutorials using Sandcastle. In geojson buildings can be seen only 2d (as footprints) and in kml experience Cesium gives an error "Unsupported geometry type: model". I want to render both 3d geometries and semantic attributes in Cesium. I have approximately 2000 buildings. So, What is the best and easiest way to visualize buildings and their attributes in Cesium? I want both visualize geometry and query semativc attributes on browser

Answer (score 1):

Cesium doesn't support citygml(.gml) directly. You can convert your buildings from CityGml to 3D Tiles(.b3dm) using FME then stream and render them on Cesium.

Answer (score 0):

not only tileset(b3dm, pnt) but glb, gltf can be used on cesium as well.

Answer (score 0):

The 3DCITYDB Import Exporter plugin allows you to convert CityGML to tileset formats:

> Export of KML/COLLADA/glTF models to be used with GIS and Digital Globe Browsers like ArcGIS, CesiumJS, Google Earth, or iTowns

The tool and documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/3dcitydb/importer-exporter). In contrast to FME it is open source and hence not depending on a license.